# how do you stop commands from stacking in the console?

Tags: python, windows-console

So basically I'm trying to make a reaction test in Python. The implementation is unimportant, but I'll leave it below:

```
def reaction():
    print("3",end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2",end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1",end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("---------------------")
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,4))
    reaction_start=int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    input("PRESS!")
    reaction_end=int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    return (reaction_end - reaction_start)
```

So basically, it gives a countdown before showing "PRESS!", and then it records the time it takes for the user to press enter. I plan to repeat this test several times so that the user's performance can be averaged over.

However, you could cheat this by pressing "Enter" before the "Press!" sign shows up. The "enter" command seems to stack and gets executed the next time the program asks for user input. In fact this seems to be the case in general not only for this function but for every input related thing in Python.

That is, if you make any input when running Python, those inputs gets inserted into the next possible point when the Windows console next asks for inputs. So If I run a Python script, and then while the python script is running, I press "up" and "enter", the program will immediately press up and enter after the script is done running and rerun the last command (i.e. repeat the function). How do you stop commands from stacking in this way?

Comment: `sys.stdin.flush()` just before your `input()`, perhaps.

Comment: what does that do sorry? does it delete all inputs that are currently being stacked?

Comment: You could use a loop like `while msvcrt.kbhit(): msvcrt.getwch()` to drain the console's input buffer.

Comment: import time
import sys

time.sleep(3)
sys.stdin.flush()
test=input("new input")
print(test)

Comment: when would msvcrt.kbhit(): msvcrt.getwch() be true and when would it be false?

Comment: `kbhit()` is true when there's at least one character in the input buffer that can be read via `getwch()`.

Comment: The implementation of the CRT's `kbhit` function calls WinAPI [`PeekConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684344) to look for a `KEY_EVENT` input record in the input buffer. In C, for your use case it would be simpler to call [`FlushConsoleInputBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683147), but the ctypes setup or PyWin32 requirement makes it awkward in Python.